# Change language file

Tags: c#, localization, windows-mobile

I create resourcefile.en-EN.resx and resourcefile.pl-PL.resx and I'm wondering how to switch between this to file inside some button in my Windows Mobile Application. It doesn't have to be changed without restarting application. I don't know where to start.

Comment: Tip: double negatives are hard to grasp. "It *doesn't* have to be changed *without* restarting application." What exactly are you saying here? That it is OK for the change to only appear after a restart, or that you *don't* want to have to restart the application?

Comment: I'v tried to say that it would be better if it could be done without restart aplication, but if it's needed i may be

Comment: The first question is why you want to override system settings? Assuming user already selected his preferred language for the whole device, you do not need to switch anything. Just detect this preference if you have to (as easy as `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`) and you are done.

Comment: @Pawel Dyda Sometimes you need to override localization, for example I have devices loaded with an English configuration and the application runs in kiosk mode so user can't change anything, but deployed to people which only speaks Spanish

Answer (score 0):

I've use this line of code to switch the current culture for my application

```
 Properties.Resources.Culture = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
```

Then you can just reload the localized strings.